# How to express "I slept through" when you didn't meant to

Tags: sentence-construction, american-english, sentence-choice

How to express the following :
Suppose I had a meeting at 9:30 am.
And I was awake lying in my bed at 9.00 am. **But then I went to sleep and woke.up at 10 am.**
Now how do I communicate this bold part in correct way to another person

1. I slept through.
   But this will sound like I intentionally slept. I was awake 30 mins before the start of the meeting.
   It's just incidentally sleep took over me without notice.
2. I was awake an hour back in bed and sleep took over me.

I feel both of them are not perfect.
But just wrote them to give an idea what I am trying to express.

Comment: We say _I overslept_ to mean that you woke up later than you intended, but it doesn't carry the implication that you were awake and then went back to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are telling a story or apologising.

If you are telling a story, you want to include the details.

> I woke up at 9, but fell asleep again until 10

You could make the story longer with more details about the time of the meeting, when you fell asleep, why you were so sleepy etc.

If you are apologising then you don't need to tell someone that you woke up etc.

> I overslept.

Because if you are awake, and you fall asleep, that is *as intentional* as not waking up at all until 10.

Comment: So is this also correct - 'I was awake an hour back, but fell asleep'